# import requests and Beautifulsoup not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am unable to import any installed module in my python script "scrapper.py".
I followed these steps:

1. Inside scrapvenv folder created a virtualenv named scrapvenv
2. activated scrapvenv and pip install requests and pip install bs4
3. created a python file "Scrapper.py" inside the base scrapvenv folder

though the pip list shows that these module are installed But import doesn't work.

Vscode shows that the python interpreter is 3.9.4 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, and assuming that you are running your script from the terminal, make sure that VSCode has selected the correct interpreter from your virtual environment, by making sure that the command line contains your environment name in brackets, like so:

```
(scrapvenv) C:\...\scrapenv\>
```

If it does not, make sure to select it manually by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P`, searching for `Python: Select Interpreter`, and choose from a list, or browse manually if you don't see your environment in the list

Comment: I can see that that the virtual env is selected "in the bracket" and I only have one interpreter which is selected "python 3.9"